# Free offline geocoding

Tags: gratis, offline

I have a list of 2000 addresses like this:

```
Macquarie Park, New South Wales
Kitami, Hokkaido
Hachioji, Tokyo
Pokemon Inc. Asahi Bldg. 7F 3-2-6 Asakusabashi Taito-ku, Tokyo 111-0053 Japan
東京都港区
```

And I want to display them on a map **without sending these addresses over the Internet**.

Geocoding addresses:

- City-level precision is OK.
- Some addresses (like the 4th one above) contain many details, they can be skipped but it might be tricky for an algorithm to find what can be safely skipped.
- Many addresses don't have the country name. Note that Google Maps find these without any problem, so I guess there usually is no ambiguity.
- Places all over the world.
- Some of the addresses use non-Latin scripts. Bonus for geocoding them too.

Output format:

- `.osm`/`.obf`/`.kml` file output is OK.
- Raw latitude/longitude output is OK too.
- If the software insists on showing results as a map, it is OK too. I don't need very detailed maps, a map where names of cities above 100000 inhabitants are visible is enough.

Requirements:

- Runs on my local computer (I can install any OS).
- Easy to install, without downloading gigabytes of data.
- Free.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6/geocoding-thats-anonymous-good-and-free-does-it-exist

Comment: The requirement to do without downloading Gigabytes of data conflicts with the "offline" requirement. Either one or the other.

Comment: @DeerHunter: The question you linked to is only for the USA, unfortunately.

Comment: @DeerHunter: I am only looking for town-level precision. A database containing coordinates of all cities above 100000 inhabitants and their address matching expressions would probably fit in 100 MB. That would be enough.

Answer (score 3):

This could be possible with the [OpenStreetMap API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API), licensed under [ODbL](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright/en).

I haven't used it for a while, but basically you define a rectangle (`bbox`, bounding box) of two points (S, N, W and E). Since the maximum area of the bounding box is limited, you'd need to repeat the query for small parts of the world (where areas with a size of Germany are typically ok).

Then you define conditions of what you want to receive. For cities, `place=city` would be such a condition. Unfortunately the catgorization of cities may be country specific, so you need to read the documentaion and find out.

Example API query for cities in Germany (roughly, since rectangled):

```
http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?node[bbox=5.87,47.27,15.04,55.12][place=city]
```

The result is quite small (155 kB) and contains relevant information:

```
<node id="17193023" lat="49.5981208" lon="11.0036532">
    <tag k="ele" v="279"/>
    <tag k="is_in" v="Mittelfranken,Bayern,Bundesrepublik Deutschland,Europe"/>
    <tag k="is_in:country" v="Germany"/>
    <tag k="is_in:country_code" v="DE"/>
    ...
    <tag k="name" v="Erlangen"/>
    <tag k="name:ta" v="எர்லங்கன்"/>
    ...
    <tag k="place" v="city"/>
    <tag k="population" v="105624"/>
    ...
</node>
```

This is an answer because:

- city level precision is available (as described above)
- the algorithm to find cities can be defined by you (some programming knowledge needed, though)
- your algorithm can handle ambiguosities
- worldwide: OSM data is really good weanwhile
- non-latin city names supported, see example above for `name:ta`
- it provides raw longitude/latitude output (see `lon` and `lat`)
- runs on your computer (you can use any programming language that can download data via HTTP)
- easy to install: no installation, it's a webservice
- without downloading gigabytes of data: small amount of data, see example above
- free: ODbL

I'm sorry that this answer still needs some custom programming, but considering the age of the question and no answers yet, I guess that your request is very specific can can only be solved like this.